# How to save a friends list in Play

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a web application which users log into. I want the users to be able to add friends (in a social network style). However, I'm not sure how to go about this using play. When I go to the view, a null pointer exception is thrown.

Here's what I've tried

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    public String username;
    public String password;

    public List<User> friends = new ArrayList<User>();

    public static Finder<String, User> find = new Finder<String, User>(String.class, User.class);

    public User(String username, String password){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void addFriend(User friend){
        friends.add(friend);
    }

    public static void befriend(String user1, String user2){
        User.find.ref(user1).addFriend(User.find.ref(user2));
        User.find.ref(user2).addFriend(User.find.ref(user1));

        User.find.ref(user1).save();
        User.find.ref(user2).save();
    }
}
```

And here is the view:

```
@(friends: List[User])

<div id="current_friends">
    @for(friend <- friends) {  <!--This is the line the error is thrown at-->
        @friend.username
    }
</div>
```

To try and test this out, when the application start I create two users and befriend them.

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app){
        // Check if the database is empty
        if(User.find.findRowCount()==0){
            User conor = new User("Conor", "secret");
            User jerry = new User("Jerry", "secret");

            User.befriend("Conor", "Jerry");

            conor.save();
            jerry.save();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how the controller calls the view:

```
return ok(index.render(User.find.byId(request().username()).friends));
```

So my question is, why is my ArrayList always null when it is initialised when it is declared?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to store a List in the Database, which is not supported by Play.
Have a look: [@ElementCollection not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386671/play-framework-2-1-1-elementcollection-not-generated-in-evolution)

It is possible when you want to use "plain" JPA and not the ebean from Play

```
@ElementCollection
List<String> stuff;
```

But it is not possible to Store complex Objects, like your "friend" Object as a list of friends in the Database.
This is where you need Associations
In this case probably ManyToMany will be the right Keyword to search for.
[Play Example @ManyToMany](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaGuide2)