# Play framework 2.1.1, @ElementCollection not generated in evolution

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1, ebean

I have a simple model, like this:

```
@Entity
public class Album extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String name;

    @ElementCollection
    public Set<String> urls = new HashSet<>();

    // ...
}
```

When I run the application on a new database, an evolution is generated but does not contain anything for the set of urls. It looks like this:

```
# --- Created by Ebean DDL
# To stop Ebean DDL generation, remove this comment and start using Evolutions

# --- !Ups

create table album (
  id                        bigint not null,
  name                      varchar(255),
  constraint pk_album primary key (id))
;

create sequence album_seq;
```

What am I missing? Is there a different way I should be making this relationship?

Edit: I'm kludging through this by adding a Url entity and putting a @ManyToOne mapping on it back to the Album, but that's really not great...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that EBean do not support @ElementCollection.

One way to do it should be to declare your Set of urls as @Transient (ie. not persisted) and have methods to manage it while keeping up to date a simple String that contains your tags comma separated. That would be this String that gets persisted in a single column.

Comment: Thanks eskatos. I should have come back to this, here's the feature request for this in EBean (from 2012): http://www.avaje.org/bugdetail-378.html. I ended up storing more details along with the url so my ManyToOne work-around worked for me, but I'll upvote you anyway :)